# How to transform many OVER/ORDER BY query calls into only one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following existing SQL query that returns the 5 previous GPS position records order by time descending for a specific vehicle and end time:

```
SELECT TOP 5 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY [Time] DESC) AS step ,[Time]
                                      ,[VehiculeID]
                                      ,[VehiculeUserID]
                                      ,[Latitude]
                                      ,[Longitude]
                                      ,[Speed]
                                      ,[Heading]
                                      ,[Altitude]
                                      ,[SatelliteCount]
                                      ,[HDOP]
                                      ,[VDOP]
                                      ,[EngineOn]
                                      ,[PrivacyOn]
                                      ,[Mileage]
                                      ,[DbInsertTime]
                                      ,[ReceivedTime]
                                  FROM [dbo].[GpsPosition]
                                  WHERE [Time] < @Time
                                    AND VehicleID = @VehicleID
                                    ORDER BY [Time] DESC
```

Right now I'm running the query multiple times per vehicleid /time tuple:

Query One:

```
SELECT TOP 5 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY [Time] DESC) AS step , [Time]
, [VehicleID]
, [VehiculeUserID]
, [Latitude]
, [Longitude]
, [Speed]
, [Heading]
, [Altitude]
, [SatelliteCount]
, [HDOP]
, [VDOP]
, [EngineOn]
, [PrivacyOn]
, [Mileage]
, [DbInsertTime]
, [ReceivedTime]
FROM [dbo].[GpsPosition]
WHERE [Time] < '2020-07-23 12:09:44.000'
AND VehiculeID = 359586014989545
ORDER BY [Time] DESC
```

...

Query n:

```
SELECT TOP 5 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY [Time] DESC) AS step , [Time]
, [VehicleID]
, [VehiculeUserID]
, [Latitude]
, [Longitude]
, [Speed]
, [Heading]
, [Altitude]
, [SatelliteCount]
, [HDOP]
, [VDOP]
, [EngineOn]
, [PrivacyOn]
, [Mileage]
, [DbInsertTime]
, [ReceivedTime]
FROM [dbo].[GpsPosition]
WHERE [Time] < '2020-07-23 12:09:00.000'
AND VehiculeID = 12345678
ORDER BY [Time] DESC
```

The tuples values are always unique.

I'm pretty sure I can do better with only one call with may be a temporary table holding the tuples created explicitely juste before?

what do you think? Is there an ever better way whith the help of some currently unknown SQL gems on my side ? I already know about CTE.

Comment: Sample data showing what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `partition by` and filter on `step`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VehiculeID ORDER BY [Time] DESC) AS step,
             p.*
      FROM [dbo].[GpsPosition] p
      WHERE [Time] < @Time
     ) p
WHERE step <= 5
ORDER BY VehiculeID, [Time] DESC;
```

I don't see a utility to have a negative value for `step`.  But if that is what you want:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VehiculeID ORDER BY [Time] DESC) AS step,
             p.*
      FROM [dbo].[GpsPosition] p
      WHERE [Time] < @Time
     ) p
WHERE (- step) <= 5
ORDER BY VehiculeID, [Time] DESC;
```

EDIT:

If you want just a subquery of vehicle/time pairs from another table, then use `JOIN` in the subquery:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VehiculeID ORDER BY [Time] DESC) AS step,
             p.*
      FROM [dbo].[GpsPosition] p JOIN
           undescribed_table_in_question utq
           ON p.VehiculeID = utq.VehiculeID AND
              p.[Time] < utq.[Time]
     ) p
WHERE step <= 5
ORDER BY VehiculeID, [Time] DESC;
```

Comment: I may have not been clearer enough in my question. I want the restriction values (@vehicleId/@Time) comming from a temporary table or another query

Comment: @OlivierMATROT . . . Your question appears to be directed at this problem:  "Right now I'm running the query multiple times per vehicleid /time tuple:"  There is no second query or table mentioned.  And this seems to be one better, because it works for *all* vehicles.  Of course, you can add a filter in the subquery for particular vehicles and times if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in table variable and handle accordingly.

```sql
DECLARE @VehicleTime table(VehiculeID DECIMAL(18,2), time datetime2)

INSERT INTO @vehicleTime 
VALUES (359586014989545,'2020-07-23 12:09:44.000'),
(12345678, '2020-07-23 12:09:00.000')

SELECT -step,
[Time]
, [VehicleID]
, [VehiculeUserID]
, [Latitude]
, [Longitude]
, [Speed]
, [Heading]
, [Altitude]
, [SatelliteCount]
, [HDOP]
, [VDOP]
, [EngineOn]
, [PrivacyOn]
, [Mileage]
, [DbInsertTime]
, [ReceivedTime]
FROM
(
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VehiculeID ORDER BY [Time] DESC) AS step , 
[Time]
, [VehicleID]
, [VehiculeUserID]
, [Latitude]
, [Longitude]
, [Speed]
, [Heading]
, [Altitude]
, [SatelliteCount]
, [HDOP]
, [VDOP]
, [EngineOn]
, [PrivacyOn]
, [Mileage]
, [DbInsertTime]
, [ReceivedTime]
FROM [dbo].[GpsPosition] as gp
INNER JOIN @vehicleTime  as vt
on gp.[Time] < vt.[Time] 
AND VehiculeID = vt.vehiculeID
) as t
where step <= 5
```